# How to short-circuit a where statement in Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I am wondering if it is possible to short-circuit a where statement when finding the first result.

Here is a sample query:

```
g.V().hasLabel('SEAT')
    where(
        __.repeat(out('NEXT').simplePath())
        .until(loops().is(gte(2)))
    )
    .in('CONTAINS')
    .dedup()
```

The de-dupe is required because there could be multiple lengths from a given vertex that have a parent on the in edge of 'CONTAINS' which has chains of vertices on the out edge of 'NEXT'.

What I would like is to short-circuit the where on finding the first time a vertex satisfies the criteria.

Here is a sample graph and query: https://gremlify.com/bwa7spaz97b/5

More clarification on the issue:

If I change the query to use `path` instead of `dedup` the results are as follows:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 15245,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15239,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 15248,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15239,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 15257,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15242,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 15260,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15242,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 15263,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15242,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ]
]
```

You can notice that there is a result (child vertex start + parent vertex) for each path that satisfies the where condition (ie. Multiple results with the same SECTION vertex).  I want the query to stop processing once it finds the first path that satisfies the where clause.

Fundamentally, I want to find each 'SECTION' vertex where there is a path of length N or greater on its child vertices.

The result I'm looking for (using `path`) would look something like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 15245,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15239,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ]
  [
    {
      "id": 15257,
      "label": "SEAT"
    },
    {
      "id": 15242,
      "label": "SECTION"
    }
  ]
]
```

I'm essentially looking for something like `whereFirst` (if it actually existed).

Comment: If you put a `path` step at the end of your query instead of `dedup` you should see that for each starting vertex, the search will end as soon as one result is found. Is that not what you are seeing? I tried with your data and just saw one result for each start (and as you noted there can be duplicate results)

Comment: I want the query to short-circuit once it finds a single chain of child vertices that satisfies the where condition for each parent.  I don't care to know about each path, I only want to know there is at least one path.  For example, using my example, with ```path``` I will get multiple results for Section ID 15239, I want it to short-circuit for each Section vertex once it finds a child chain of vertices that satisfies my where condition.

Comment: OK thanks that helps clarify. You want to not have to do the `dedup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query as follows to filter out duplicates inside the where

```
g.V().hasLabel('SEAT').
    where(
        __.repeat(out('NEXT').simplePath().where(without('x')).store('x'))
        .until(loops().is(gte(2)))
    )
    .in('CONTAINS')
```